# Creating canonical references for Selenium basics

Tags: discussion

As discussed here: [What are our standards about Selenium questions?](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295/what-are-our-standards-about-selenium-questions/)

Everyone seems to agree that we ought to provide useful information to beginner Selenium users. To reduce the load of repeated questions with slight variations, let's create a series of "canonical" questions and begin aggressively merging/closing duplicates into them. This way everyone wins: the new Selenium users get their questions answered in a complete, well-written way, and we don't have to repeat ourselves ad nauseum.

Reply here if you see a need for such a reference on a topic, including the list of questions that should be merged.

Open concerns:

- Should we mark these questions in some way?
- We will need either high-rep users or moderators to start closing the duplicates once a good answer exists; I can't do that part alone

Comment: I can help with closing the dups.

Answer (score 4):

## Canonical Question: How do I do cross-browser testing in Selenium?

*Or some such. Something giving an overview of browser-specific issues like needing a separate driver, opening the same test in two browsers, et cetera*

Duplicates that (will) need merging:

- [How to open multiple browsers using webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5431/how-to-open-multiple-browsers-using-webdriver)
- [What is the best way to have a SpecFlow project run across multiple browsers?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-specflow-project-run-across-multiple-browsers)
- [Maintaining automation framework for different browsers like IE and FF](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/323/maintaining-automation-framework-for-different-browsers-like-ie-and-ff)
- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/how-to-run-a-test-script-in-a-different-browsers-by-using-selenium-webdriverjs-a
- [Getting nose test runner to execute a test against multiple browsers / configurations?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/getting-nose-test-runner-to-execute-a-test-against-multiple-browsers-configura)
- [How can i start my session in other browser rather than firefox in Selenium WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/how-can-i-start-my-session-in-other-browser-rather-than-firefox-in-selenium-webd)
- [Is Selenium the right tool for browser compatibility testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/is-selenium-the-right-tool-for-browser-compatibility-testing) (though this one is interesting on its own)
- [Selenium-2 Webdriver browser support](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/selenium-2-webdriver-browser-support)

Answer (score 3):

## Canonical Question: How do I use select boxes in Selenium?

Question is now here: [How do I work with dropdowns in Selenium Webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver)

As a meta note, please let me know if there's any other languages that it'd be helpful to have examples for.

Duplicates that (will) need merging:

- [How to Retrieve the values from a drop down using selenium-WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/how-to-retrieve-the-values-from-a-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver)
- [Using Selenium (C#) how do I select an item from a drop-down list](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6601/using-selenium-c-how-do-i-select-an-item-from-a-drop-down-list)
- [Unable to locate element in a dropdown](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/unable-to-locate-element-in-a-dropdown/9440#9440)
- <strike>[How to compare values from the list or from dropdown list in webdriver (Java)?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7868/how-to-compare-values-from-the-list-or-from-dropdown-list-in-webdriver-java)</strike> Turns out to be not related
- [I want to select the value from the dropdown](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/i-want-to-select-the-value-from-the-dropdown)
- [Webdriver: Selecting element by position in drop-down menu](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/webdriver-selecting-element-by-position-in-drop-down-menu)
- [how can i get all the dropdown values in a list](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10443/how-can-i-get-all-the-dropdown-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

## Canonical Question: How do I get started with Selenium

Question is now here: [How does one get started with web test automation using Selenium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/how-does-one-get-started-with-test-automation)

Duplicates that need merging:

- [How does a Manual tester become expert in automation testing in selenium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9830/how-does-a-manual-tester-become-expert-in-automation-testing-in-selenium/9877#9877)
- [How is Selenium RC different from Selenium Web driver and some good pointers for a naive beginner to learn to scripting please? Thanks!](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/how-is-selenium-rc-different-from-selenium-web-driver-and-some-good-pointers-for)
- [How can Manual QA's without a programming background learn Automated Testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9096/manual-qa-looking-to-get-into-automated-testing-no-programming-background)
- [How is Selenium different from other GUI automation tools?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/725/how-is-selenium-different-from-other-gui-automation-tools)
- [Where can I find information on getting started with Selenium 2?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/295/where-can-i-find-information-on-getting-started-with-selenium-2)
- [what is the best way to write automated end to end user scenarios?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-automated-end-to-end-user-scenarios) (maybe)
- [script to test auto login website](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/script-to-test-auto-login-website)
- [What are the advantages of web driver over selenium RC?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/what-are-the-advantages-of-web-driver-over-selenium-rc)
- [Need help to find Selenium Webdriver contents and the learning sites](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11967/need-help-to-find-selenium-webdriver-contents-and-the-learning-sites)

Answer (score 1):

## Canonical Question: How do I download files during a Selenium test?

*Also possibly: How do I interact with native file download box. Whichever wording works.*

Let's use this one as a merge target, as it has several good answers: [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

## Canonical Question: What are the different methods to upload files using Selenium WebDriver?

Related Questions:

1. [Selenium: Unable to automate file upload](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/selenium-unable-to-automate-file-upload)
2. [Upload image via ajax form with selenium and Python](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/upload-image-via-ajax-form-with-selenium-and-python)
3. [How to handle a native OS (Ubuntu) file upload window in selenium webdriver with python?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-handle-a-native-os-ubuntu-file-upload-window-in-selenium-webdriver-with)
4. [Using Selenium webdriver with chrome browser - Junit or java - how to upload a file from desktop(or any folder in pc) to application](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7675/using-selenium-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-junit-or-java-how-to-upload-a-f)
5. [Unable to upload a file using selenium/web driver running with java](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/unable-to-upload-a-file-using-selenium-web-driver-running-with-java)
6. [FileUpload using selenium RC and java](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5638/fileupload-using-selenium-rc-and-java)
7. [Handling Image upload](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/handling-image-upload/8541#8541)
8. [Selenium: Unable to automate file upload](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/selenium-unable-to-automate-file-upload/11766#11766)

Comment: Posted: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12851/3218

Comment: Looks good. I could post two other methods to upload files - using Robot class and using AutoIT along with Selenium

Comment: Go for it :) I was going back and forth on whether I wanted to include the "wrong" way of doing it when the right way is so straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

## Canonical Question: How to debug selectors in webdriver

This should be a thing. More info coming soon.

Comment: We need this somewhere: "What minimum information must I provide if I don't want my Selenium selector question to be downvoted?"

Comment: See also http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-information-must-i-provide-in-a-selenium-selector-question.

Answer (score 0):

## Canonical Question: What is "Implicit Wait" and when do I use it?

I've seen a lot of confusion around this topic, but I don't have time to write this up ATM

Comment: This is a difficult one. I have never seen any documentation that states when to use implicit wait. See [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-should-one-use) post.

Comment: I was prompted to mention this by confusion around people adjusting the implicit wait timer when what they really wanted to do was explicitly wait. Maybe "how do i slow down Selenium" would be a better topic, discussing thread.sleep, implicit, and explicit waits